# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient error when using Picasso offline capability - Android

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, okhttp

I am working on a project which has offline feature capability using Picasso library in Android. So far, I'm just following the tutorial.

This is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
}
```

This is my Picasso setting:

```
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this,Integer.MAX_VALUE)); //always give me the error to this line
    Picasso built = builder.build();
    built.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
    built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
```

And this is how I call Picasso in my `actvity.java`:

```
Picasso.with(this.getApplicationContext()).load(stringUriProfile).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(mUriImageProfile, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                //the function fires whenever the picasso doesnt find picture from offline way
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(stringUriProfile).into(mUriImageProfile);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't fully understand the problem and this solution.  It seems that in recent revisions to the OkHttp library, the package that contains `OkHttpClient` changed.  The 2.5.2 version of Picasso expects to find it in the old package, `com.squareup.okhttp`.  One solution is to replace:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

There may be better solution.  This is the only one I have found.

Comment: Nice save my day bro

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep `okhttp3`, you can use [Jake Wharton's solution](https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader):

add to gradle:

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
```

initialize with:

```
 OkHttpClient client = // ...
 Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
     .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
     .build()
```